# How to add large file (in GB) in Xcode project?

Tags: ios9, xcode7, mapbox, filesize, mbtiles

I am working with Mapbox Framework. I have generated MBTiles file which I want to use in my project (for iPhones and iPads) but that file is having size of 3GB (which I can't use in project). When I added that file in project, it created a build of 3.29GB.

When I gave reference of that file too, created build in GBs.

Is there any way that I can use that file in my Xcode project without increasing build size?

Comment: Is this app going on the app store?  Or rather did you hope that it was going on the app store?

Comment: You want to use GBs of data in your app without having GBs of data in your app....  Put the file on a smart server and request small amounts of it as needed?

Comment: @trojanfoe : Yes we are planning it to upload on app store. But not with this size. :(

Comment: Phillip Mills has it right.

Comment: @PhillipMills : Can you please tell me how can I do the same?

Comment: In general, sure: write (or find) server-side software to handle requests for tiles, define a protocol between your app and the server that makes sense for your requirements, implement the network communication.

Comment: We are using it as a offline so it will work as offline map. We cannot request anything from server in this case.

Comment: In that case, you seem to have two conflicting requirements: 1) put a 3GB file on your device, 2) don't put a 3GB file on your device.  I don't think there's an answer that satisfies both of those conditions.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Phillip is correct in the comments above, uploading the mbtiles is your best option not only for reducing app size but increasing app performance. Instead of setting up your own server, if you sign up for a Mapbox account you can upload the file and display it within your app. [Heres a help guide](https://www.mapbox.com/help/uploads/) that will get you started. Note that you might need to pay for a standard plan as the limit for free is 1GB.

Additionally, another option is to [use Mapbox Studio to style a map](https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-mapbox-studio-1/) in the same manner you did with your mbtiles.

Hope this helps out!